# How do I keep the AS3 Camera class from adding black bars?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, camera, activex, webcam

Under certain conditions, picking a resolution with [`Camera.setMode()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode()) adds black bars to the camera input, "letterboxing" it. I understand that `setMode()` uses some kind of hidden algorithm that picks a resolution from one of your camera's available resolutions and then crops it to fit your desired dimensions, but apparently sometimes it would rather add black bars than crop it.

This behavior is dependent on what camera I'm using. Some cameras seem to always crop and never letterbox. This may be related to what available resolutions they have. But what's really strange is that the letterboxing only ever happens when I try it in a Flash Player ActiveX control, like in Internet Explorer. It doesn't happen when I try the exact same SWF in Flash Player Projector or Google Chrome. This seems to imply that different Flash Player versions use a different algorithm to select and fit a resolution to the desired dimensions.

Here's a very simple example of code that's been creating this problem for me. In this case I'm providing a 4x3 resolution to setMode(), which means it must be selecting a 16x9 resolution even though 640x480 is one of the camera's available resolutions.

```
public class Flashcam extends Sprite 
{
    private var _camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera("0");

    public var _video:Video;

    private var _width:int = 640;
    private var _height:int = 480;

    public function Flashcam() 
    {

        _camera.setMode(_width, _height, 15);
        _video = new Video(_camera.width, _camera.height);

        addChild(_video);

        _video.attachCamera(_camera);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to stop Camera from letterboxing its input? If not, is there some way to tell whether or not it's being letterboxed and which camera resolution has been automatically selected so that I can write my own code to account for it?

Comment: Usually the `camera.width & height` properties will report the real width/height used (if different than what you passed to `setMode`).  Have you tried this on multiple webcams (as perhaps the camera itself is putting the black on in order to meet the requested resolution)?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that I've tried this on multiple webcams. The behavior seems specific to certain cameras but I've determined that it's not the camera that's adding the bars. And `camera.width` and `height` seem to return the size with the black bars already added.

Comment: You mean the fourth argument on `setMode()`. And setting it to `true` is what favors the area. And it's true by default.

Comment: Yes you are correct,  was going off memory.  I seem to have skipped your entire second paragraph, sorry about that.